# How do I get my Authenticated user info? As Id and such?

Tags: authentication, cakephp-4.x

I'm new at the latest cakephp versions and hadn't used the Authentication Component until now. I'm trying to validate a user being an admin but can't find how to get the user id to get it, nor how to get the identifier. `$this->Authentication->getIdentifier()`
throws an error that the identifier does not exist.

In general I'm trying to do a little cms to learn new framework usage and such. Haven't used it since 2.x

Comment: Take a look at https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/identity-object.html

Comment: I did, didn't understand it and it didn't work...@LinkinTED

Answer (score 4):

It's `$this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getIdentifier()` to get the id. You can also use the get()-method to get other fields, for example  `$this->Authentication->getIdentity()->get('username')` returns the username.

Comment: It should be noted this is how you access the logged in user in a Controller. In a View you need to use `$this->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity')->getIdentifier()` or `$this->getRequest()->getAttribute('identity')->get('username')`